# How to use existing parametrized selector in createSelector method

Tags: typescript, redux, ngrx

I want to create a selector from parametrized selector. The way I understand is that this would emit only when particular item is updated, which is what I want.

```
const getFeatureState = createFeatureSelector<FragmentsHierarchyState>(MY_FEATURE);

const getItem = createSelector(
    getFeatureState,
    (state: FeatureState, props: { itemId: string }) => {
        return state.items[props.itemId];
    }
);

const getItemValue = createSelector(
    getItem, // <<< How to pass props here?
    (state: ItemState) => return state.x + state + y
);
```

I don't want to do following, because I don't want new values emitted each time feature state is updated:

```
const getItemValue = createSelector(
    getFeatureState,
    (state: FeatureState, props: { itemId: string }) => {
        return state.items[props.itemId].x + state.items[props.itemId].y;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getFeatureState` selector, should also have received the props normally...

If that's not the case you can use a factory function

```
const getItem = ({ itemId: string }) => createSelector(
    getFeatureState,
    (state: FeatureState) => {
        return state.items[itemId];
    }
);
```